# how to get latest record from the database having same id in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to to get latest record having the same id. For example
I have table

```
 ID | Created_at
  1 |2016-04-26
  1 |2016-04-20
  1 |2016-04-18
  2 |2016-04-27
  2 |2016-04-19
```

I want to get result like this

```
ID  | Created_at
1   |2016-04-26
2   |2016-04-27
```

How do I do this in Laravel? I was only able to order the record by descending order. Don't know how to pick the latest record of each ID. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try using Collections service from laravel , and use `last()` method. Example:

```
$data = ModelName::all();
$last_data_object = collect($data)->last();

//try to see the object using var_dump()
var_dump($last_data_object);
```

I get it from https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-last

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `whereRaw` to getting last records in `groupBy` laravel

```
$data = Table::whereRaw('Created_at IN (select MAX(Created_at) FROM table GROUP BY ID)')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way, it will give you the max grouped ID which will be the latest:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), Created_at
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, Created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for help. I was able to solve this by

```
DB::raw("SELECT ID,created_at FROM <table name> a WHERE created_at=(SELECT max(created_at) FROM <table name> b WHERE a.ID=b.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::raw('SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `Created_at` ASC');
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Include the directive **Db**

`$id = DB::table('your_table')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->value('id');`

If you have user_id.

`$id = DB::table('your_table')->where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->value('id');`